# Erro: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

Estou executando meu app, porem ele retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
```

E simplesmente estou executando o App e abrindo direto meu ListView com um botão..

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView listaPrincipal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listaPrincipal = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstPrincipal);

}

public void adicionarVaga(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VagasActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void alterarVaga(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlterarVagas.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lstPrincipal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btAddVaga"
    android:onClick="alterarVaga"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/gridLayout" />

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="9"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNumeroVaga"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="ID"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPropretarioVaga"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Ocupante Atual"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="7"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2" />

</GridLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+"
    android:id="@+id/btAddVaga"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="adicionarVaga"/>
```

Ficarei grato para demonstrar o que está faltando em meu código..
Obrigado

Comment: O ListView não funciona por si só, ele precisa de um Adapter. Você está setando seu Adapter? Se sim, pode postar o código dessa parte? Mais informações neste tutorial:
http://blog.alura.com.br/criando-uma-lista-com-listview-no-android/

Comment: O xml que postou é tudo o que se encontra em *Activity_main.xml*?

Comment: Esse XML em ActivityMain.xml ou é incompleto, ou está errado. Não se pode ter mais do que um único nó pai no XML de leiaute do android!

Comment: Pessoal, acabei descobrindo que o problema foi habilitar o método onClick sem subItem para clicar, pois o banco de dados ainda estava vazio. Acabei mudando a lógica do meu banco de dados e tambem do XML em questão e irei usar o método setonItemSelected().., obrigado pela ajuda. Assim que possivel eu posto o código..